# Regex for d h m time string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a problem to check my string for correct time input.
It should be possible to write it like this: (number)d (number)h (number)m
Each part can be left out and the numbers don't have a limit (e.g. 2352h).
Some possibilities are the following:

- 2424d 23h 15m
- 523h 526m
- 235d 252m
- 829d 926h

I use the following RegEx which works really good but has one problem, which is that one letter can be used multiple times (e.g. 52d 23d).
I want that each letter can be used once. Whitespaces are optional.
This is what I have for now:

```
^((\d{0,9}[dh]\s?){0,1}(\d{0,9}m)?){1,3}\s*$
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^(?=.*[hmd]$)\d+(?:d\s*)?\d*(?:h\s*)?\d*(?:m\s*)?$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9iTVwc/3)

**Explanation**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?=.*[hmd]$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the string ends with either `d`, `h` or `m`
- `\d+(?:d\s*)?` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit followed by optional `d` followed by 0+ spaces
- `\d*(?:h\s*)?` - matches 0+ occurrences of a digit followed by optional `h` followed by 0+ spaces
- `\d*(?:m\s*)?` - matches 0+ occurrences of a digit followed by optional `m` followed by 0+ spaces
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Another alternative: [`^(?=.*[hmd]$)(?:\d+d\s*)?(?:\d+h\s*)?(?:\d+m\s*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/9iTVwc/5)

Comment: Thank you! works great! I also grouped them with brackets like this:
^(?=.*[hmd]$)(\d+d\s*)?(\d*h\s*)?(\d*m\s*)?$

Comment: Glad that worked :) You can use the alternative regex too.